# Cannot assign data to a pointer; why it is invalid?

Tags: c++, memory-management

Trying to do what should be a simple memory management assignment. I have a class called `Vehicle`, and I am trying to repeatedly assign an instance of the class Vehicle to a `Vehicle *` pointer. However, whenever I am trying to assign a value to the pointer, the program crashes with the following output:

```
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

My `int main()` is very simple:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Vehicle * ptrVehicle;
    int d, w;
    char input;

    while (1) {
        cout << "Enter q to quit, otherwise create vehicle object." << endl;
        cin >> input;
        if (input == 'q' || input == 'Q') {
            break;
        } else {
            cout << "Enter the number of doors > \t";
            cin >> d;
            cout << endl << "Enter the numer of wheels > \t";
            cin >> w;
            cout << endl;
            if (ptrVehicle) delete(ptrVehicle);
            ptrVehicle = new Vehicle(w,d);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

From my understanding, if ptrVehicle is a non-null pointer, the memory it points to will be deleted so a new object can be created. But this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you don't need to test whether a pointer variable holds a null pointer before deleting it. `delete` knows about null pointers. So `if (ptrVehicle) delete(ptrVehicle);` can be written simply as `delete ptrVehicle;`.

Comment: You should also validate that `operator>>` is actually successful before using the value it outputs to you. If the input fails, the value won't be what you are expecting.

Answer (score 6):

You never initialized your pointer, so `delete` is undefined behavior. You can initialize it before your loop.

```
Vehicle* ptrVehicle = nullptr;
```